# use ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to crateBean programmatically but cannot get the bean ; Spring

Tags: java, spring

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ct = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();

ct.refresh();
ConfigurableListableBeanFactory bf = ct.getBeanFactory();

Ad bean = (Ad) bf.createBean(Ad.class);
System.out.println("bean ="+bean);  
System.out.println("size= "+bf.getBeansOfType(Ad.class).size()); // print  0
```

Ad class ,here is the Ad class information ,AD extends AbstractAd class:

```
public class Ad {

 @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "ad[adid=" + this.getId() + "]";
   }
```

}

here is the log:

```
[DEBUG] Creating instance of bean 'com.Ad'
[DEBUG] Finished creating instance of bean 'com.Ad'
bean = ad[adid=null]
size= 0
```

in my opinion ,**size should be 1** ,what is wrong?

**ps:** finally I use  GenericApplicationContext  and BeanDefinition  and success createBean and get From context ,

```
   GenericApplicationContext ct = new GenericApplicationContext();

    ct.refresh();

    ConfigurableListableBeanFactory bf = ct.getBeanFactory();
    System.out.println("--------------start------------/n--------------------------/n-------------------/n");

    BeanDefinition definition = new RootBeanDefinition(Ad.class);
     ct.registerBeanDefinition("sampleService", 
    System.out.println(bf.getBeansOfType(Ad.class).size()); //print 1
```

log:

```
[DEBUG] Creating instance of bean 'sampleService'
[DEBUG] Eagerly caching bean 'sampleService' to allow for resolving potential circular    references
[DEBUG] Finished creating instance of bean 'sampleService'
1
```

but I still wonder : **why getBeansOfType(Ad.class).size() is 0** after ClassPathXmlApplicationContext creteBean ?

Comment: @phil I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, so I've removed my answer. I think you need to clarify further what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @phil you use Spring to instant a Hibernate bean?

Comment: @jonathan I want to programmaticly create bean ,and get the Beans;

Comment: @OQJF it is not the cause ,I think

Answer (score 2):

in the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext you are not passing any XML, if you pass any spring config xml then it will show expected result. also `Ad bean = (Ad) bf.createBean(Ad.class);` will create a bean of the class only. but it will not add it into sprig context.

in the second code you are registering your bean by using registerBeanDefinition method. that way it is showing to expect result.

I have tried following code and it work

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext classPathXmlApplicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/Beans.xml");
        classPathXmlApplicationContext.refresh();
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = classPathXmlApplicationContext.getBeanFactory();
        System.out.println(beanFactory.getBeansOfType(HelloWorld.class).size());
```

Comment: I find " This is effectively a superset of what autowire provides, adding initializeBean behavior." in java doc . autowire  register into context ; can u do deep work to show Ad bean = (Ad) bf.createBean(Ad.class); will create a bean of the class only.